# GGPLOT add boxplot from different column

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

This is a subset of my dataframe:

```
Name <- c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16', '17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32')
Gruppe <-c('A','A','B','B','C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C',  'C',  'C', 'C','A','A','B','B','C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C',  'C',  'C', 'C')
Group <-c('A','A','B','B','CA','CA','GE','GE','SA','SA','ST','ST','STR','STR','WA','WA')
Location <-c('CO','UF','CO','UF','CO','UF','CO','UF','CO','UF','CO','UF','CO','UF','CO','UF','CO','UF','CO','UF','CO','UF','CO','UF','CO','UF','CO','UF','CO','UF','CO','UF')
Value <-c(3.5,6.6,1.9,9.2,5.2,4.4,6.8,3.2,2.7,7.1,4.3,9.8,4,8.3,5,6.1,3,8.4,4.8,9.1,1.4,4,8.9,3.6,4,8.4,6.1,2.5,4.5,9.3,6.7,4.6)

data <- data.frame(Name, Gruppe, Group, Location, Value)
```

I would like to plot this with ggplot separated according to "Group".
My Code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Location, y=Value, fill=Group)) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("chartreuse3", "yellow2",
                             "firebrick3", "cyan4","darkgoldenrod2","darkorange4","darkgreen","deeppink3","darksalmon"))
```

[image]

However, I also want to add "C" in "Gruppe" as an additional boxplot that should show up in the legend, summarizing the "Groups" from "CA" - "WA". Is there any way to do it? Preferably without changing the dataset itself, its original form is very big. The boxplot for this should be next to "A" and "B" and look the same, ie in width.

Thank you for every help, if there is something missing I of course will explain.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if it's not what you desire to see

[image]

code;

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Location, y=Value, fill=Group)) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_boxplot(data=dplyr::filter(data,Gruppe=='C'),aes(x=Location, y=Value, fill=Gruppe),alpha=0.1)+
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("chartreuse3", "yellow2",
                             "firebrick3", "cyan4","darkgoldenrod2","darkorange4","darkgreen","deeppink3","darksalmon"))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. No, sadly not. I actually had this version as well, but I would like for "C" to be next to "A" and "B" and looking "the same" as the rest, so in width etc.